# Comments in KeystoneJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

The demo in the KeystoneJS website has a "comment on posts" module on it, while when you generate your own KeystoneJS Application, it doesn't come with it. How can I add it on my KeystoneJS Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Yeoman Generator](https://github.com/keystonejs/generator-keystone) for KeystoneJS is not a duplicate of the demo site. You can view [the code for the demo site](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone-demo), but there are fewer customization options. You can also use the Yeoman generator to make the site the way you want, then copy the appropriate models and routes from the demo site if all you're looking for is the comment-on-post functionality.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139039/discussion-on-answer-by-shea-belsky-comments-in-keystonejs).